# Move HTTP GET request into a JSON array in Magento 2 REST API (V1/customers/search)

Tags: magento2, php, api, rest-api, json

Is it possible to put the content of this rest api in a json array to put in GET parameters instead ? And if yes, what should the code look like ?

```
curl_init("http://my.website.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=email&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed my question with http_build_query() and json_decode().

```
$api = "rest/V1/customers/search";

$json = '
{
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "email",
                        "value": "%",
                        "condition_type": "like"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
';
$j = json_decode($json);
$get_params = http_build_query($j);

$ch = curl_init("http://my.website.com/index.php/".$api."?".$get_params);
```